# Subsetting data at an irregular interval in an R function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, subset, apply

I have a function like this

```
extract = function(x)
{
a = x$2007[6:18]
b = x$2007[30:42]
c = x$2007[54:66]
}
```

the subsetting needs to continue up to 744 in this way. I need to skip the first 6 data points, and then pull out every other 12 points into a new object or a list. Is there a more elegant way to do this with a for loop or apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note: if `2007` is truly a column name (you would have had to explicitly do this, R defaults to converting numbers to names starting with letters, see `make.names("2007")`), then `x$"2007"[6:18]` (etc) should work for column reference.

To generate that sequence of integers, let's try

```r
nr <- 100
ind <- seq(6, nr, by = 12)
ind
# [1]  6 18 30 42 54 66 78 90
ind[ seq_along(ind) %% 2 == 1 ]
# [1]  6 30 54 78
ind[ seq_along(ind) %% 2 == 0 ]
# [1] 18 42 66 90
Map(seq, ind[ seq_along(ind) %% 2 == 1 ], ind[ seq_along(ind) %% 2 == 0 ])
# [[1]]
#  [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
# [[2]]
#  [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
# [[3]]
#  [1] 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
# [[4]]
#  [1] 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
```

So you can use this in your function to create a list of subsets:

```r
nr <- nrow(x)
ind <- seq(6, nr, by = 12)
out <- lapply(Map(seq, ind[ seq_along(ind) %% 2 == 1 ], ind[ seq_along(ind) %% 2 == 0 ]),
              function(i) x$"2007"[i])
```

Comment: the column name is actually jan2007_tempK, I was just trying to be concise, oops! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

we could use

```
split( x[7:744] , cut(7:744,seq(7,744,12)) )
```